missing some icons in aurelia slickgrid 6
I am on aurelia slickgrid 6 with bootstrap 5. I am missing some icons like small sorting icon on top of column or in the side like in the picture. Am i missing some library or maybe aurelia slickgrid needs some css loader ?

Here is my package versions:

I can multi select rows but it also has icon missing. Baiscally funcionality is working with icons. 
On firefox, if i zoom on the icon, i see 

Fixed it with npm i font-awesome

The older version of Aurelia-Slickgrid required Font-Awesome 4.7 which you might have forgot to install. You could use another font library but when you do, then you will need to override all icons unicode, so it's easier to just install Font-Awesome 4.7. The newest version of Aurelia-Slickgrid no longer requires Font-Awesome since it now uses SVG

thanks. one side question, for aurelia 1, aurelia-slicgrid 6.6.5 is the last reommended version?

yes 6.x for Aurelia 1

you can also refer to the Compatibility Table which is linked in all Releases that I do.
